# ERROR ITMS-90596: "Invalid Bundle. The asset catalog at 'Payload/MyApp.app/Assets.car' can't be processed."

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, ipa, macos-high-sierra, itmstransporter

I created an app with Xcode 11.6 (11E708) on macOS Catalina 10.15.6 (19G73). I archived and exported this app to an ipa file with Xcode.

Now, I want to upload this ipa file with Apples Transporter 1.1.1 (1171) running on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 (17G11023).

When starting the upload, I get the following message after few seconds:

> ERROR ITMS-90596: "Invalid Bundle. The asset catalog at
> 'Payload/MyApp.app/Assets.car' can't be processed. Rebuild your app,
> and all included extensions and frameworks, with the latest GM version
> of Xcode and resubmit."

How can I solve this problem while still being able to upload the ipa file with Transporter from macOS High Sierra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution:

I downloaded `Xcode 10` from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/. Be aware to download `Xcode 10` because all newer versions like `Xcode 10.1` aren't compatible with High Sierra and won't work.

After the download, I installed and started Xcode once.

After that, I closed Xcode.

Now, the Transporter app worked like a charm with no errors at all.

Hint: If that doesn't work for you, maybe try to restart your Mac.